# Cadenas de caracteres - Verificar que una palabra NO se encuentra dentro de una cadena

Tags: python, string, substring

tengo la siguiente consulta... ¿Cómo verifico que una palabra no se encuentra dentro de una cadena de caracteres?. Por ejemplo, para verificar si está puedo hacer esto:

```
if palabra in cadena:
         print(...)
```

Ahora, si yo quiero checkear lo contrario, que la palabra no esté en la cadena ¿Cómo sería?.
De antemano muchas gracias!! Saludos.

Comment: Negando la condición `palabra not in cadena`

Comment: Bueeena, Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para chequear que una cadena cualquiera no es parte de otra:

```
if palabra not in cadena:
    print(...)
```

Eso no más.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!